# Creating Teams from GraphExplorer fails with forbidden even after granting Teams.Create permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been trying to create a Team using delegated permissions from a desktop app and it fails with error "Message: Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/amer/templates/api/team, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: Forbidden, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000"

I also tried this with Graph Explorer and it seems to show Forbidden error.
"error": {
"code": "Forbidden",
"message": "Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/amer/templates/api/team, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: Forbidden, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000x-

My understanding is that if one of the permissions listed is granted, the Teams creation should work. I have granted Teams.Create and Group.ReadWrite.All , yet it fails with forbidden issue.
This forbidden makes me wonder if its a permission issue, but at the same time it is complaining about templates so I am confused.
I am using the GraphAPI NuGet for C# and below code

```
var team = new Team
{
    DisplayName = "Test Team",
    Description = "Test Team’s Description",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()                
    {
        {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
    }               
};
var createdTeam = await graphClient.Teams
                 .Request()
                 .AddAsync(team);
```

I see quite a lot of posts on this issue from November 2020 but that seemed to be issue at Microsoft's end that got resolved. And plenty of other posts saying adding the owner in team creation etc could cause the issue. So I simplified it to bare minimum required and still it fails with forbidden error. Should the delegated user be an admin for this to work?

Update: I do have permission to create Teams via UI so I should be ok in the delegated(effective) permissions front. So why would it fail with forbidden status code.

Comment: I am trying this at my end could you please confirm if you are facing this issue with other templates as well?

Comment: Ok I tried 'educationStaff' template. But I get "Error when calling Middle Tier. Message: ''. Error code: 'Forbidden'. Status code: Forbidden.","errorCode":"Unknown". Maybe my org doesn't support that template. How do I know what templates are supported?

Comment: We were able to repro the issue. we have raised a bug and the concerned team is looking into it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for getting back to me. Is this tracked in git? if so could you provide a link?

Comment: @AshleyAsh1990 -  We are tracking it in our DevOps & you will not have access on it. We will share you the updates on the bug, once it is fixed.

Comment: @AshleyAsh1990 - Could you please confirm if your issue is resolved?

Comment: i have the same error, both standard and educationStaff but still same error

Comment: Could you please let us know how you are creating the Team?

Comment: Are you using graph explorer or C#? Please share any sample/documentation that you are following? We are able to create team using graph explorer with delegated permissions and able to create a team using C# with application permissions.

Comment: i'm using c# right now, http client calling graph endpoint, but even using graph explorer, same error

Comment: Could you please share the steps that you are following? Also please share the client request ids for the scenarios it is failing.

Comment: @MicheleIetri - Could you please share the above asked details?

Comment: @MicheleIetri - Hope you are doing well !!   Can you please share the client request ids, so that we can check the error logs and investigate on your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.

```
{
   "template@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
   "displayName":"My Sample Team",
   "description":"My Sample Team’s Description",
   "members":[
      {
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
         "roles":[
            "owner"
         ],
         "user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user id')"
      }
   ]
}
```

This was my payload. When creating team with application permission we have to specify an owner. In my case owner does not have a valid license. To create teams with owner, the owner must have office 365 E1 or Office 365 E3 or Microsoft business standard license. After specifying users with proper license the teams created successfully.